# django-silk shows 0 time for all queries

Tags: python-requests, silk, django-silk

Using django 2.2.14 and django-silk 3.0. Just return overall time but the queries are all 0.Is some wrong about the version of django-silk or django?How can I solve the bizarre issus.

```
Package Version Django 2.2.14 django-silk 3.0.2
```

### silk show image

[image]

Comment: trying out `django-silk` and seeing the same issue... setting `SILKY_PYTHON_PROFILER_RESULT_PATH` doesn't seem to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick answer

Set `SILKY_PYTHON_PROFILER_RESULT_PATH` in your `settings.py` for example:

```
SILKY_PYTHON_PROFILER_RESULT_PATH = "/var/profiler"
```

You must ensure the specified directory exists.
In the [documentation of silk](https://pypi.org/project/django-silk/) says It supposed to use media folder if it's not set but somehow is not working.

```
# If this is not set, MEDIA_ROOT will be used.
SILKY_PYTHON_PROFILER_RESULT_PATH = '/path/to/profiles/'
```

Comment: I'm working on windows and as a short note: `SILKY_PYTHON_PROFILER_RESULT_PATH = os.path.join('C:\\', 'temp')` does work, but `SILKY_PYTHON_PROFILER_RESULT_PATH = 'C:/temp/'` does not.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things you need to ensure are set.

The main important one is adding the following env flags before your run your application.

In your `.env` add:

```
SILKY_PYTHON_PROFILER=True
```

If you do have `SILKY_INTERCEPT_FUNC` method in your `settings.py` ensure it returns the correct boolean value based on the request e.g.

```py
def SILKY_INTERCEPT_FUNC(request):
    """log only session has recording enabled."""
    return 'record_requests' in request.session
```

In addition, ensure you add the silk middleware in the correct order

In `settings.py` add the following:

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...
    'silk.middleware.SilkyMiddleware',
    ...
]

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'silk'
)
```

> Note: The middleware placement is sensitive. If the middleware before silk.middleware.SilkyMiddleware returns from process_request then SilkyMiddleware will never get the chance to execute. Therefore you must ensure that any middleware placed before never returns anything from process_request. See the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process-request) for more information on this.

Ref: https://github.com/jazzband/django-silk#installation

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with an endpoint that had a long loading time.
Notised that `MySQL` aborted connection with `Error 1153 - Got a packet bigger than 'max_allowed_packet' bytes`

To fix it update the `my.cnf` in `/etc/mysql/`

```
net_buffer_length=1000000 
max_allowed_packet=1000000000
```

or run:

```
set global net_buffer_length=1000000; 
set global max_allowed_packet=1000000000;
```